# vim with python: how to map :silent make | copen to function key in vimrc

Tags: python, vim, makefile

Thats it, what I have in my vimrc and I would like it to work is :

```
set makeprg=python\ %
nmap <F5> :silent make | copen
```

It doesnt work, it echoes :silent make and doesnt run or report errors in script. But if I just type in Vim

```
:silent make | copen
```

I get my desired result.

I'm using GVim 7.4 on windows vista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing your python code not linting it. A quick google shows [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) and [Python - check syntax and run script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Python_-_check_syntax_and_run_script). There is also [synstastic.vim](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) if you want a heavier handed approach.

You mapping has the following problems:

- the pipe, `|`, is not escaped. Use `<bar>` instead.
- As a general rule of thumb should be using `*noremap` unless using `<Plug>` mappings
- You need to execute the command by adding `<cr>` at the end
- Optionally use an `:autocmd` to execute `:cwindow`/`:copen` after `:make`. e.g `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * cwindow`
- Optionally make a new command for this action: `command! -nargs=* Smake silent make <args>`. Now you can do `:Smake` instead of `:make`

Your new mapping:

```
nnoremap <F5> :silent make <bar> copen<cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :map
:h <bar>
:h :au
:h QuickFixCmdPost
:h :cwindow
:h :cope
:h :compiler
:h write-compiler-plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `map` commands don't accept the pipe character as command separator and takes it as input, so you could replace it with `<bar>`, like:

```
:nmap <F5> :silent make <bar> copen<CR>
```